# Convert DataTable to String Array through Extension Method

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, datatable

I know there are plenty of similar threads out there but my requirement is little different. The basic requirement is to convert a `DataTable` to **array of strings**. I am able to do that by creating an `Extension` method to do that work for me.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
     public static object ToStringArray(this DataTable dt, params object[] columns)
     {
          //if specifically columns are provided then returns item array values for these columns.
          if (columns != null && columns.Length > 0)
          {
              //return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new[] { //here i want to iterate through columns params }).ToArray();
          }
          else
          {
               return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new[] { x.ItemArray }).ToArray();
          }
      }    
}
```

If I don't provide column names explicitly then it perfectly returns all rows values as strings array.

```
var dtData = dataTable.ToStringArray();
```

But what if i provide column names

```
var dtData = dataTable.ToStringArray("Column1", "Column2", "Column3");
```

then how can I iterate through `columns` to get only provided columns values in this chunk of code

```
if (columns != null && columns.Length > 0)
{
     return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new[] { //here i want to iterate through columns params }).ToArray();
}
```

I know I can do that by hard coding the column names as follow:

```
var dtData = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new[] { x["Column1"], x["Column2"], x["Column3"] }).ToArray();
```

or

```
var dtData = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new[] { x.Field<string>("Column1"), x.Field<int>("Column2").ToString(), x.Field<string>("Column3") }).ToArray();
```

**How can I get this working in my Extension method and by using `param object[] columns` values?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a select on the columns parameter. I have changed the type from object[] to string[] here.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static object ToStringArray(this DataTable dt, params string[] columns)
    {
        //if specifically columns are provided then returns item array values for these columns.
        if (columns != null && columns.Length > 0)
        {
            return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => columns.Select(c => x[c]).ToArray()).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new[] { x.ItemArray }).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would probably add `ToArray` to the `columns.Select` part: `columns.Select(c => x[c]).ToArray()`. Otherwise, a nice answer

Comment: You did it. Thanks you very much buddy. And @Pikoh thank you very much too, Your suggestion made this answer perfect according to my requirement.